# All Post/Get Requests Pending After req.login Passport + React + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, passport-local

After I have successfully authenticated a user and the user gets logged in,
all requests made to my API get the Pending status.
My tests conclude that this only happens if and after **req.login** has run.

```
req.login(user, loginErr => {
        if (loginErr) {
          return next(loginErr);
        }
        return res.send({ success : true, message : 'authentication succeeded' });
      })
```

Full Login Passport code

```
  router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      if (! user) {
        return res.send({ success : false, message : info.message });
      }
      
      req.login(user, loginErr => {
        if (loginErr) {
          return next(loginErr);
        }
        return res.send({ success : true, message : 'authentication succeeded' });
      })

    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

From what I can understand, there must be something blocking all requests made after.

**Client code**

```
let config = {
                headers: {
                  'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
              }
    
              const user = `username=${username}&password=${password}`;
    
              await axios.post(`/auth/signup`, user, config)
              .then(res => {
                // USER IS LOGGED IN
                if(res.data.success) {
                  //this.closePopup(); // POPUP gets closed.
                }
              })
```

What could be the cause of this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `app.use(passport.session());`
It needed to be placed under the route.